# Windows Service and Windows Phone

Tags: wcf, windows-phone, windows-services

I would like to develop a service to be installed on Windows Phone device (Embedded 8.1 Handheld), in order to send data to the device.

Any idea how to began to face with this?

Comment: it is not possible to create a service that runs on a windows phone.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Ken, i would like to run some process in backround, this process will pull some data from remote server and store it on local resource (sql compact or xml file), and this data will be displayed on user interface windows phone app. I'm reading some info about ScheduledTaskAgent... Thanks!